# How to Import Multiple Camera Tracking from Nuke to Blender?

Tags: tracking

I'm attempting to merge multiple scenes into a single video in Blender using multiple camera tracking. I have about 10 different sequences that I'd like to align seamlessly, as they all share the same 3D object background but were shot from different angles. Is there a method to delay the start of the camera tracking, perhaps by 50 frames or so, just like how image sequences function works? Currently, when I play the video, all imported cameras start moving from frame 1, but I need them to start at different times based on the sequence.

Thank you in advance! I also wish you a wonderful holiday season!